# Looking for C# graphical library for 2D flat generation

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d

I have to work on a small project on my studies in C#. It takes data from XML and according to them generates flat (like architecture plan for flat) with maybe some sprites (lamp and light around it? doors?). User can use mouse to move some things around (like ball or something showing user where in the flat we currently are) + some text labels.

Is there any nice and easy-to-use library to get this done - I started my C# adventure about a week ago and I am not really experienced.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer higher-level API, choose either WPF or Silverlight: create a Canvas control, and place whatever elements you like. You can scroll/zoom by e.g. setting up a render transform. Those two are very similar, WPF has more functionality but only works on Windows PCs, Silverlight is lighter but works everywhere, including OSX and Windows Phone.

If you want complete control on what exactly is displayed and how, you might want to consider lower-level things, like e.g. Direct2D. It’s IMO much harder to do, and requires deeper understanding of 3D graphics pipeline. However, if you have previous experience with e.g. Direct3D or OpenGL API (regardless on the programming language), it might be even easier for you to learn D2D than WPF or Silverlight.

All of them are parts of the .NET framework — so they are all stable, mature, and well documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to look at them soon. I had some experiences with OpenGL, but there were some turbulences, so I think I'll stick to higher-level APIs. Gonna look for some examples of these, If you have any - feel free to post them so I can compare :)